Help me understand this high voltage amplifier circuit
This question is about the circuit which also present in here:
Help me understand this high voltage amplifier circuit for driving a piezo actuator

I have some follow up questions:

What is the reason (what are the pros) of using two inverting transistors (Q5 and Q6). or the reason of Q5 is only to adjust the voltage level to -Vcc as of source of Q6? if i want to use non-symmetrical rails (Vcc,0) Q5 stage can be omitted?
Still not sure why there are diodes in the feedback of the OpAmp. Isn't R9 which is controlling the total gain, and hence the OpAmp output (Q5 Base). I ran some simulations and the diodes doing nothing (in the circuit as a whole).

UPDATE:
Simulation Circuit

OpAmp output:


Follow the link in the question you linked. It provides a fuller explanation.

@Andyaka I did, and it still doesn't explain the diodes in the feedback.
It says "D1 and D2 keep the op amp from saturating" but from my observations, the OpAmp is not saturating even without the Diodes. I think it was true if there were not R9 feedback

Show your simulation circuit and show your plots of the op-amp output voltage.

@Andyaka updated in the post

Yes, I see what you mean. Q5's base emitter region is also acting like a diode too so, the explanation is a little suspicious. What was the corresponding output p-p voltage after the push-pull transistors?

100 Vp-p. Total gain of -20 (inverting)

But, the circuit could deliver much more than this (looking at your power rail voltages). The diodes may come into play then.

Diodes like that are often designed in, and designed to not conduct in normal operation. In ABnormal operation however, they can result in the circuit recovering more quickly from perhaps a sudden overload, or the rails coming up in the wrong order.

Q5.
It allows the op-amp rails to be independent of the output stage rails. Q5 shifts the voltage down to whatever -VCC is.
If you want to use 0 V for both your op-amp negative supply and the output stage negative supply and lose Q5, then make sure that the opamp output will go right down to Q6's base voltage. And invert the feedback. And check performance and stability with the loss of Q5's gain.
The diodes.
You will often see circuits where diodes like that don't conduct during normal operation. However, during ABnormal operation, they can be very useful. You say gain is controlled by R9 - not when the output is short-circuited it isn't. If the op-amp was allowed to saturate against the rails, it would take a lot longer to recover from an output overload or short than if clamped like that.
That amplifier has four power rails. What happens if one comes up late? For instance if there's a non-zero amplifier input, and the relevant power output supply rail is late.
I do have a question about the validity of the original circuit. D1 appears to make the driving of Q5 marginal, I'd like to see at least another diode shift in voltage there, perhaps making Q5 one of a diff pair. And Tim Williams commented that he'd like to see some emitter degeneration for Q5 - I certainly agree.

Speaking of marginal, Q5 is hard driven by IC1 out, making gm wildly inconsistent; an emitter resistor would go a long way to linearize it.

@TimWilliams can you elaborate on that?

@TimWilliams I'm not sure. Q5 is within the feedback loop. Putting an emitter resistor will also increase the swing at the output of IC1. I'd say OP should do it only if compensation is not possible. One could also replace R7 by a current source.

R7 as a CCS would vastly raise loop gain, making instability guaranteed.

@TimWilliams sure, but then there are other ways of stabilizing around the feedback loop.

So like emitter degeneration?

@MFU See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/708306/311631

@TimWilliams around the feedback loop! :)

I'm not in the mood for a complete analysis of this, but there are some things worth mentioning in more than comments.  So, this will be sort of a partial answer.
There are two glaring issues I take with this circuit.
First, some background.
When considering sub-circuits or building blocks, it is useful to consider their interconnection in terms of bounded operating ranges; what is the output range, what is the input range, and how closely do they match.  What happens when one range exceeds the other?
The output range of one block, obviously needs to meet or exceed the input range of the next.  Otherwise it can't drive the input to its full required range.  Mind, "required" depends on application, and intentionally limiting range has value in many places.  So this is the design requirement, the intent, not necessarily what a given block can or will handle in and of itself.
The output range probably should not exceed the input range by a wild margin.  Typical consequences are integrator windup (all that time spent beyond the nominal input range is wasted time recovering from clipping, say), or wear or failure outright (say, avalanching a diode junction, or blowing up the input entirely).
The op-amp here can swing say +/-10V and 20mA, way more than needed to drive Q5 VBE, at any temperature, at any current it could possibly need.  This includes causing E-B avalanche when clipping output-high. The op-amp output range is very mismatched to Q5.
Not that we need to use the full voltage and current range, we're not trying to extract maximum power from the op-amp -- indeed, we should generally avoid using the full current range (op-amps are voltage-mode components, they work best when lightly loaded), and any voltage range we leave unused means excess saturation, recovery time, when it goes into clipping.  The system goes terribly nonlinear, and perhaps even chaotic.
This isn't necessarily a problem, but it's a warning sign that one should expect dependent, inconsistent -- nonlinear -- behavior.  Fine, it's an amplifier, probably not going to break into full random chaotic hissing and garbage -- but this is were it begins, and why bother inviting that demon into your house when you can keep things clean and well-behaved with but a few changes?
The second problem is that, Q5 cascaded into Q6, together give probably several hundred times voltage gain.  The feedback loop only attenuates that by 1/20th, so the loop gain is most likely way more than the op-amp -- a unity gain stable type -- can handle.
We have an oscillator.
The resolution to this is almost trivial: add emitter degeneration resistance to Q5 and Q6.
Q5's common should also be referenced to op-amp supply, so that the full op-amp output range maps to the full collector current range needed from Q5, thus avoiding E-B breakdown.  A single-supply amp can also be used, assuming the input CM range can be adjusted to suit.
Likewise, Q6 must have emitter degeneration such that its maximum collector current is had at minimum op-amp output (towards Vee), and this will be twice the pull-up current (i.e. that from Q3, which should be a similar design to save bias current -- it doesn't need to be a current mirror but can be resistor biased).
Note that Q5 and Q6 are merely acting as level translation and voltage gain, so should be designed for exactly this and nothing more: evidently, about the 20 gain needed to make up for the feedback network's loss.  Then the op-amp can be unity-gain stable -- or, at least, have a much better chance at it, since there will still be excess phase shift due to collector load capacitance (particularly of Q6).
One last potential issue: it's not clear between the original diagram and simulation what supply voltage is intended, but ±360V will absolutely not work with MJE340/50, which is rated 300V only, and 720V minimum is required for simulation settings as shown.  (HV BJTs have pitiful SOA, and I would strongly encourage a MOSFET solution in this case.  But this requires still further changes, which aren't in scope here.)

I think the reason for Q5 is three-fold:

to bring the DC voltage lower such that Q6 is properly biased and amplifies well.
Amplifiy
to keep the negative feedback operation.

If you want Q6, you need Q5 to keep the feedback negative.
You could also connect the output of the Op-Amp directly to the Q1 and Q2 buffer, but, apparently, more loop gain was needed for this particular design.
